# How to pass a list of string as a parameter after grouping them in SSRS?

Tags: arrays, reporting-services, parameters, grouping

In SSRS, I made a Dataset that returns (roughly) informations about a person and information about a company, according to their ties :

```
#####################################################################
# Name     # Roles # LinkedTo # Birthdate  # Adress # CompanyAdress #
#####################################################################
# Joe      # VP    # Corp A   # 1945-01-01 # 123    # 456           #
# Joe      # CEO   # Corp A   # 1945-01-01 # 123    # 456           #
# Joe      # VP    # Corp B   # 1945-01-01 # 123    # 543           #
# Bill     # CEO   # Corp B   # 1950-12-31 # 234    # 543           #
#####################################################################
```

My reports contains 2 sections. The first one display the info of the person, the 2nd one, their link.

```
######################################
# Joe    # 1945-01-01   # Roles(???) # <-- This is a subreport
######################################
# Linked to : Corp A (VP)            # 
# Linked to : Corp A (CEO)           # 
# Linked to : Corp B (VP)            #
######################################

######################################
# Bill    # 1950-12-31   # ???       # <-- same subreport
######################################
# Linked to : Corp B (CEO)           #
######################################
```

The subreport is in a group, filtered on the Name column of the dataset.

I want to list all the roles (VP, CEO and VP for Joe, CEO for Bill) of my persons.

The grouping seems to cause my subreport to only receive the first value (Joe : VP, Bill : VP) instead of an array.

I indicated that my parameters @Roles can receive multiples values. But it seems to not be enough.

How should I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your parameter may be it's AVAILABLE or Default values being not set correctly if you are getting the first indexed item in an array.  EG: If I set up a parameter to go with me and it is super simple like:

```
declare @Temp table ( id int, Name varchar(8) )

insert into @Temp values (1, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (2, 'C');

Select 
  Id
, Name
from @Temp
```

If I have a grouping that is having subreports and other things it may be setting only one value EVEN if it is allowing multiple.  If you want your parameter to be agnostic of scope(meaning it does not care where in the report it is to determine values).  You can set it's available values and default values to be 'get values from a query' and set up a dataset met to only ever return the same static values it will only get those values EVERY TIME.

You do this to a report (as it seems you have) that is in a whole different RDL file and set it up to have a parameter of only the name and forget about anything else.  Then you are relating it to another report by name only as its variable.  I would do testing that you can put in a different name and it always comes up with the same data everytime.  Generally when reports are nested and there are multiple parameters or shared sets is when there are problems.  Never have two reports where there is a parent child relationship share a dataset IMHO as you can have issues where groupings change levels.

In theory if you can put in 1 and your subreport gives two rows of 'A' and 'B' if you set up a pretend parameter @Id tied to a report and added the line: 'Where Id = @ID'.  To test my report I should put in 1 or 2 and it should give two different values.  If it does I know this report is working as designed and the calling of it is wrong some how.  If it does not then the sub report is the issue first.  If a report is not displaying the same size and data as if you tested it with that same person then there is a problem with the orientation and sizing or the grouping is causing only part of the report to display.  I have done reports the collapse on subreports that then make the width grow once the report is displayed so I know if you are using SSRS 2008R2 or higher this will work.

My example was super simple but you could apply the data to a subreport with a regular dataset that is not shared with the main report (especially with predicates).

Comment: I'm passing my "single/list of roles" as a parameter to my subreport. In fact, I pass all the data as parameters to the subreport. I'm not sure I get what you are explaining too. Are you suggesting I pass my "personID" to another query/dataset to get my list of roles?

Comment: I am suggesting you pass a single string or int and have the subreport do all the work.  But ensure that the dataset is not shared between the two reports.  EG: If Joe is those levels you can set a report to show that by merely passing in 'Joe' as a parameter to evaluate 'Select Roles from tables where name = @Name'.  Same with Bill.  Then you have a master report that on each line or group just states 'Give me subreport for (Name)'.  Then the subreport does all the work of a one to many relationship and you just present it with the person related to the roles.

Comment: It's what I would have naturally done, but that means I get 1 request per person in the subreport and I've been told to limit my number of sql request to the minimum to maximise performance. Wouldn't it be much slower like this?

Comment: How many records are you talking about 100k's, mil's, 10's of mils', etc?  Generally speaking you can still use caching techniques on SSRS to limit overheard.  Also you are limiting scope ON DEMAND by doing 'select thing from subset where person = @person'.

Comment: I'm not even sure it will be hundreds. Although, there are other bottleneck (I'm getting much data from slow views).

Comment: More accurately : My query will often return < 100 records. But the database will supposedly grow to a ~10 mils records.

Comment: Cache your view, proc, query then by using a shared dataset.  Publish the dataset.  Go to server where it is published.  Manage > Caching > (set it up once a day or more).  If you are dealing with data that is directly hitting production you have issues with your queries no matter what your front end is so I would work on a multitude of indexing, caching, isolation level that does not harm the DB.  I would suggest if it is small now, but will grow, set up a nightly job to do a data warehouse of only the measurements you want to their own tables and have those tables fully indexed.

Comment: I went with a subdataset in the subreport. We'll see how it goes, because yes, it's "I enter new data and then I print (async request) a report containing that data". We'll optimize if needed later on. Thanks.